# Самым простым (короткий, понятный код) способом записать полученные из POST данные в MySQL сохранив названия полей?

Tags: php, mysql

Прошу помощи!

От сервиса приема платежей, html запросом на мой push.php приходят данные вида:

```
{"SALEDATE":"2021-08-25 4:11:32", "REFNO":"23456", "REFNOEXT":"", "ORDERNO":"7", ...., ,
"HASH":"4aa30dc0d6f67293bee9cee168b90524"}
```

в которых больше 50 полей. За один раз приходит только один набор данных (одна строка БД)

Мне нужно все эти поля (их там больше 50 штук) записать в БД MySQL в столбцы с такими же именами.
Во всех примерах предлагают конструкцию, где каждый параметр POST (!)вручную нужно ассоциировать с нужным полем БД

Но это же как то неправильно, что ли...
есть ли какой то "правильный" способ записать все полученное в POST в поля БД в столбцы с теми же именами?

Целостность полученных данных предварительно проверяется через HASH.
Соответственно, есть 100% уверенность, что все поля БД в пришедшем POST будут в наличии и с правильным форматом данных

=======================

Немного усложню задачу, но это дополнительно и не обязательно.
К примеру поля ORDERNO и REFNO в БД писать не нужно и в БД нет колонок с такими именами.
Т.е. пишем только те данные из POST, которые есть в таблице.

Comment: *Но это же как то неправильно, что ли...* Это - ПРАВИЛЬНО.

Comment: Не могу вам запретить, но это "дурная работа"...

Comment: Написать простой, логичный и понятный, да ещё и быстрый, запрос - дурная работа? только потому, что в нём много символов? Ну это Ваш выбор.

Comment: Неужели менее логично было бы выполнить это одной "штатной" командой, особенно если АБСОЛЮТНО уверен в целостности данных?

Comment: *Неужели менее логично было бы выполнить это одной "штатной" командой* А такая штатная команда - она существует? что, нет? тогда о чём вообще речь-то? *особенно если уверен в целостности данных?* Ну-ну... Всё, что получено снаружи, не заслуживает доверия по умолчанию, и должно быть проверено. И если потом будет мучительно больно, то хотя бы не потому, что ничего не сделал, а потому, что где-то ошибку допустил.

Comment: В конце концов - напиши ты хранимку, которая примет этот JSON, разберёт его на части, составит текст запроса и выполнит его. И будет тебе счастье и простой `CALL stored_proc({JSON})` в программе.

Comment: Вы можете считать информацию о колонках таблицы и на основании этой информации записать входящие данные из json в БД. Но для этого имена колонок должны соответствовать атрибутам json, типы данных тоже должны совпадать. Можно ещё забирать данные после вставки и считать хэш, проверяя его с эталоном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE parse_and_save_json_to_table (param JSON)
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO test SET ',
                  GROUP_CONCAT(columnname, 
                               '=''', 
                               JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(param, CONCAT('$.', columnname))),
                               '''')) query
    FROM JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(param),
                    '$[*]' COLUMNS( columnname VARCHAR(64) PATH '$')) columns
    INTO @sql;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
END
```

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b5bbcff594118752bd9f2ed99a915db)

---

По просьбе товарища [@Ипатьев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179379/%d0%98%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%b2) - [<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9877c4012f816f6d74aa029250a230b) с универсальным решением, которому чхать на символы, требующие экранирования.

Comment: [ай-яй-яй](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c40cb65cff868e94a93a8d21be2e6615)!

Comment: @Ипатьев А это уже пусть сам рихтует. Автор ведь "АБСОЛЮТНО уверен в целостности данных".  По идее он должен ещё и знать, что такое криминальное может попадаться в передаваемых значениях. Увы, prepared statement не умеет динамическое количество параметров.

Comment: Ну вот опять мы приходим к проблеме "приватный чат vs. публичный ресурс". Если бы стаковерфлой был приватным чатом, то без проблем. А для публичного ресурса этот ответ too localized для одного автора у которого "всё под контролем". Нет, я понимаю что этот ответ по-своему хорош - в качестве курьёза, в качестве иллюстрации средств SQL. Я просто к тому, что "автора устроит" не может быть оправданием. Все-таки, это публичный ресурс, и подразумевается, что приведённое решение будет использовано не только автором

Comment: @Ипатьев Против подобных рассуждений я тоже ничего не имею. Но считаю, что создание непременно универсального решения, накрывающего ну все и всякие возможные варианты - далеко за пределами задач и целей ресурса. Всё-таки он позиционируется как Q&A, т.е. его предназначение "найди, пойми, примени", а не как набор отлаженных библиотек "бери и пользуйся, не думая, что там под капотом".

Comment: Как пользователь, я его именно так и использую, в режиме "бери и пользуйся". Когда у меня вопрос по git или там bash. И всегда рад, когда решение подходит для моего случая, а не только для каких-то завиральных хотелок автора

Comment: @Ипатьев Ок, уговорил. Добавлена ссылка на универсализованное решение.

Comment: отличная идея кстати. остаются конечно имена полей, и с джейсоном это особенно опасно, поскольку слишком соблазнительно скинуть полученный с фронта джейсон прямо в запрос, но скажем  для проверенного на сервере набора полей решение как раз подходит

Comment: @Ипатьев Ну аналогично можно добавить бэктики вокруг имён полей, а на случай, что и в имени поля есть бэктик, обработать реплейсом и удвоить - и тогда даже в именах полей можно рисовать любой бред, сервер справится.

Comment: либо просто удалить их нафиг, потому что пробел или там дефис - это ладно, но бэктиков в имени поля явно не должно быть :)

Comment: @Ипатьев Синтаксис допускает, и это явно описано в Reference Manual.

Comment: СПАСИБО!
У меня реально МЕЖСЕРВЕРНЫЙ обмен данными между моими двумя серверами, целостность данных, проверяется хеш-суммой и всё, что может содержать невалидные данные отсекается еще на взлете (первичная проверка, перед парсингом).
Спасибо за пример и выход за рамки привычного, когда данные приходят с сайта и действительно могут содержать всё что угодно.

Answer (score 3):

> каждый параметр POST (!)вручную нужно ассоциировать с нужным полем БД

Это проблему легко решить, если применить такую штуку как *программирование*.

То есть мы пишем небольшую программу, которая собирает запрос для нас.

Нам нужен будет только список имён полей, которые мы хотим добавить в запрос. Как для того чтобы вставлять только нужные, так и для **безопасности**. Поскольку без такого списка мы тут же нарвёмся на SQL инъекцию.

После этого мы легко сможем получить список имён полей через запятую, отформатированный для mysql, ну а получить строку из знаков вопроса и совсем просто. Таким образом мы получим готовый к исполнению запрос

```
INSERT INTO table (поля через запятую) VALUES (?,?, ...)
```

Ну и собственно код:

```
$columns = ["SALEDATE", "REFNO", "REFNOEXT", "ORDERNO", ...,];
$insert = '';
$values = '';
$params = [];
foreach ($columns as $col) {
    if (isset($input[$col])) {
        $insert .= ($insert ? "," : "") . "`$col`";
        $values .= ($values ? "," : "") . "?";
        $params[] = $input[$col];
    }
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO table ($insert) VALUES ($values)";
```

дальше обычным порядком выполняем запрос, например для PDO (и mysqli начиная с версии 8.1)

```
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($params);
```

или mysqli старых версий:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($params));
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Т.е.  мы все же вынуждены "полуавтоматически" составлять запрос к БД? 
Составлять массив, что то там ассоциировать...
Я надеялся, что есть более продвинутые механизмы, позволяющие прямой директивой указать "добавь эти данные в БД сопоставив названия полей и столбцов".  
Ведь это же как бы стандартная штука, когда нужно просто через POST добавить строку в БД, странно, что приходится делать это "применяя программирование"...

Comment: А то что вы штаны вынуждены каждый день надевать, вам не кажется странным? С голым задом-то щеголять куда естественнее

Comment: Интересно, что "составить массив" и скопипастить готовый на блюдечке код займет меньше времени, чем писать недовольный комментарий. Но по какой-то причине на комментарий время есть, а на то чтобы решить уже свою проблему и забыть её - ну прям совсем нет сил. Только и остаётся, что жаловаться.

Comment: Не-не-не, никакого недовольства, СПАСИБО вам огромное!!!
Просто я привык "добивать" подобные темы до идеала, и просто поинтересовался, а нет ли более продвинутого подхода.
Что касается штанов, то их то как раз когда то не было, потом их приходилось шнуровать на ширинке, а теперь придумали молнию... я только об этом. =)

Comment: Хорошо, такая аналогия. Вы когда обедаете - просто валите в одну тарелку борщ, котлеты, компот, макароны - и потом эту массу хлебаете? или все же едите по отдельности? Некоторые вещи должны быть разделены. В частности пост и база данных. Фантазии на тему "а вот должен быть волшебный метод, который все за меня будет делать - задача-то стандартная!" - это какая-то адова смесь невежества с инфантильностью. А не "идеала".

Comment: И это. Не надо менять тему. Вопрос не в застежке штанов, а в их наличии. А молнию вам пришили в этом ответе.